# How to use REGEX in bigquery for a string

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am having trouble extracting a string in my dataset using REGEXP_EXTRACT in bigquery. Below are my strings and desired outputs:

```
STRING: Gas Safe_160x600_v2b   DESIRED OUTPUT: 160X600
STRING: Gas Safe_60x150_v2b   DESIRED OUTPUT: 60X150
STRING: Gas Safe_100x40_v2b   DESIRED OUTPUT: 100X40
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Few options are using SPLIT or  REGEXP_EXTRACT as in below example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT text, 
  SPLIT(text, '_')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] extracts1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(text, r'_(.*)_') extracts2
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - result is

```
Row text                    extracts1   extracts2    
1   Gas Safe_160x600_v2b    160x600     160x600  
2   Gas Safe_60x150_v2b     60x150      60x150   
3   Gas Safe_100x40_v2b     100x40      100x40
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this expression:

```
([0-9]+x[0-9]+)
```